# How to fix mismatching childNodes with Vuetify select value saved in Nuxt store?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I'm saving Vuetify `v-select` value to Nuxt store. It works but I'm getting a mismatching childNodes error in the console each time I **refresh** my page.

A way to fix it to set `test` to any value of the `select`, but I need it to be equal to `null` at first use.

How should I fix it?

[image]

[image]

`components/Test.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    value: {{ $store.state.test }}
    <v-select
      label="Test"
      :value="$store.state.test"
      :items="testItems"
      @change="updateTest($event)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      testItems: [
        { text: 'Foo', value: 'F' },
        { text: 'Bar', value: 'B' },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async updateTest(e) {
      await this.$store.dispatch('commitTest', e)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`store/index.js`

```js
export const state = () => ({
  test: null,
})

export const mutations = {
  TEST_UPDATE(state, payload) {
    state.test = payload
  },
}

export const actions = {
  async commitTest({ commit }, payload) {
    commit('TEST_UPDATE', payload)
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the SSR content is not equal to the one after hydration. You could click on the error to see where this is coming from but it's probably because of the value of `$store.state.test`.

You could either set those in a `created` hook rather than directly or you could wrap your content coming from Vuex into a `<client-only>...</client-only>` tag. That way, it will not be generated on the server but only during client side rendering.

More info on this awesome article: https://blog.lichter.io/posts/vue-hydration-error/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand why `test: null` variable works when set in the component and not when set in the store.

Comment: If you disable the JS on the page, do you still have your Vuex store populated (is `$store.state.test` in your template)? I'm not sure that the store is populated in every case automatically, you maybe need to use `nuxtServerInit` for the state to being populated. Check this lifecycle: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle/ Maybe calling a Vuex action in the `created` hook may help to have the state populated when server side rendered, not sure.

Comment: Also, is `null` a valid `option` value? Shouldn't it be `'' `, or empty string?

Comment: If I set `test: 'F'` or `test: 'B'` in the store, I don't get this error. But as soon as I set anything else, including `null` or empty string `''` as value, I get this hydration problem.

Comment: Using `<client-only>...</client-only>` works well, however I still hope I can find a nicer solution.

Comment: Try comparing the rendered content with JS and without it to see why the DOM is unhappy.